# formatted price in angular

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Looking to comma format price in thousands :-> 
Requirement of the functionality:
1.formatting should be live (not when we do out of focus)
2.I need to implement it in `angularjs` such that the value is available in scope
3.If possible should be as `directive` so we can re-use at multiple location

There are two plugin which does the job but not live .Does it on focus out
1. https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-numeric-directive
2. https://github.com/FCSAmerica/angular-fcsa-number

i have created a demo here which uses the first plugin 
http://plnkr.co/edit/TS922MDy4Ne9jS0PMiUQ

Comment: Have you see the angular directive i10n, who allows to format text from library of resources. With that, you can format text in date, price ...

Comment: I don't know this would fix the problem. But using the second plugin you provided 'FCSAmerica', open the plugin's js file and change elem.on('blur') to elem.on('keyup') and change elem.on('focus') to elem.on('keypress').

Comment: @JonathanTheBrosh can you give me a link

Comment: @Farzad-yz you mean angular-numeric-directive ryt

Comment: @AutoMEta This plugin 'angular-fcsa-number'

Comment: @all Please have a look at the demo..currently it does on focus out

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://angularjs.org and download locals ressources in i18n directory. When you do it, add script of localization that you want.

```
<script src="YourDirectoryOfResources/angular-locale_fr-fr.js"></script>
//or other region.
```

And to use it, you can do something like this {{amount | currency}}, {{myDate | Date:'shortDate'}}.